# How to check whether the current tensorflow version is at least a specific version in a python script?

Tags: python, tensorflow, version

I would like to make sure that my tensorflow module is at least a certain version (for example, 1.13.2) inside my Python script. For me, it's not quite clear how to do this easily.

The following is one example I tried:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import re

match = re.match("(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+).*", tf.__version__)
base = 100
num1 = match.group(1) * base ** 2 + match.group(2) * base + match.group(3)
num2 = 1 ** base ** 2 + 13 * base + 2 # Corresponds to 1.13.2

assert num1 >= num2, ("The required version is at least 1.13.2")
```

The above code has several problems.

1) If some version number is more than 100 (e.g. 1.12.801), it won't work.

2) The code itself is very ugly.

I know that the above is definitely not the way to go.
Could you suggest any good ways?

Comment: Just do `(*map(int, tf.__version__.split('.')),) >= (1, 13, 2)`. There is also a [Semver Python package](https://python-semver.readthedocs.io) if you want to be able to compare more advanced version numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that the easiest solution is splitting the version number by the dots, and compare the parts converted to int.

```
reqVersion = "1.13.2"
for reqPart, part in zip(map(int, reqVersion.split(".")), map(int, tf.__version__.split("."))):
    assert reqPart <= part
    if reqPart < part:
        break
```

Comment: Actually the solution of @jdehesa is even more concise

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is from last year, but I'd just like to provide the PEP compliant way for doing this.

```py
from packaging import version
import tensorflow as tf

assert version.parse(tf.__version__) >= version.parse('1.13.2')
```

`packaging` is a Python built-in module, and the more you can use built-in modules with your code, the better.

Comment: Great! I think this should be the new accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf

their=tf.__version__.split(".")
our="1.13.2".split(".")

lessflag=False


for i in range(3):
    if(int(our[i])>int(their[i])):
        lessflag=True
        break
    elif(int(our[i])<int(their[i])):
        lessflag=False
        break


if(lessflag):
    print("not supported")
```

Comment: if compared by strings, e.g. 1.2.0 would be greater than 1.13.2

Comment: It's still comparing strings. You need to convert the parts to int.

Comment: try "1.13.2" with "1.2.2"
also "2.0.0" with "1.13.2"

Comment: One of the errors has been fixed, but it still gives a false positive to "1.13.2" with "1.2.*".

Comparing numbers as strings works correctly ONLY if they have the same number of digits.

Comment: Check it again. Your code gives back True for their="1.1.0", and False for "1.2.0"

Comment: Yes, that works correctly. But 1.2 is also a smaller version than 1.13

Comment: since when is 2 > 13?